# autocompletion jquery in symfony 3.3.6

Tags: jquery, symfony

As the title says, I want to do 2 search bars:
1-To find the job
2-To search for the city and if a user is looking for a craftsman in a chosen city, I will display the artisans who are in the city he is asking for. In the style of the site: https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/

But I don't know how to get there.

Thank you.

Comment: You should really try and do this yourself first and then post any specific problems you encounter. The question is too broad as is.

Answer (score 0):

My Controller :

```
class LayoutController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // On crée l'objet ville
    $ville = new Villes();

    // On récupère le formulaire
    $form = $this->createForm(VillesType::class, $ville);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // On génère l'HTML du formulaire
    $formView = $form->createView();


    return $this->render('layout/layout.html.twig', ['form' => $formView]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/ville/{cp}", name="ville")
 */
public function villesAction($cp)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cp = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Villes')->findOneBy(['cp' => $cp]);

    if ($cp)
    {
        $ville = $cp->getVille();
    }else{
        $ville = null;
    }
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    return $response->setData(['ville' => $ville]);
  } 
 }
```

My JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.ville').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length === 3){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ville/75001' + $(this).val(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('pas mal !!!')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.ville').val(data.ville)
                    console.log('ville okkk')
            }
        })
    }
})
```

});